# Could not reload changes to file [C:\...\UserController.groovy]: Cannot get property 'instanceControllerTagLibraryApi' on null object

Tags: grails

Use:
-Windows 8
-Intellij IDEA 14.14
-grails 2.5.1
-JDK 8u51

*** Using IntelliJ IDEA:

1) I think new project
2) I use a simple controller: "User" properly "String name"
3) Run the application
3) I do make this easy modification to the controller: When I create a new User should show "Hello!" on the console.
4) After changing me it appears on the console:

"08/04/2015 12: 43: 51.315 [Thread-9] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager - Plugin [controllers: 2.5.1] Could not reload Changes to file [C: \ Users \ Ivan Velazquez \ IdeaProjects \ Demo \ grails- app \ controllers \ demo \ UserController.groovy]: Can not get property 'instanceControllerTagLibraryApi' on null object "

5) No changes were made, obviously, when I create a new User no "Hello!" on the console.

*** Using the Windows console:

The error is different:

"08/04/2015 12: 43: 51.315 [Thread-9] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager - Plugin [controllers: 2.5.1] Could not reload Changes to file [C: \ Users \ Ivan Velazquez \ IdeaProjects \ Demo \ grails- app \ controllers \ demo \ UserController.groovy]: Can not invoke method getPropertyValue () on null object "

I searched the error in several forums but can not find solution.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug for Windows + Grails, it thinks that it fails to reload the controller if you make changes to it. In most cases, the controller *has* actually updated and reloaded, but it still shows an error. If you have problems, you can restart the grails server to see your changes.

Comment: It's what I do. The error persists. Every time I make a change in a driver stop the application and re-run.